# Verify Pythagorean Law for Normed Linear Space / Inner Product Space

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

> Given **x** $ = (1,1,1,1)^T$ and **y** $ = (8,2,2,0)^T$
>
> 1. Find vector projection **p** of **x** onto **y**
> 2. Compute $||$**x**$-$**p**$||_2$ , $||$**p**$||_2$ , $||$**x**$||_2$
>      (which are 2-Norms) and **verify that the Pythagorean Law is satisfied**

1. I know how to do part 1, and I found and confirmed **p** $=(\frac{4}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, 0)$
2. For part 2, I got

   $||$**x**$-$**p**$||_2 = \sqrt{2}$

   $||$**p**$||_2 = \sqrt{2}$

   $||$**x**$||_2 = 2$

   I don't quite understand how to verify the Pythagorean Law when it is only valid if **x**⊥**y**. We can check **x** and **y** are not orthogonal by performing the standard inner product of <**x**,**y**> which does not equal $0$.

Comment: $\mathbf x-\mathbf p$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf p$.

Comment: Please do not just delete questions that got an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$p=\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\|y\|^2}y$$
we have
\begin{align}\langle x-p, p\rangle&=\langle x,p \rangle -\|p\|^2 \\
&= \frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\|y\|^2}\langle x,y \rangle -\frac{\langle x,y\rangle^2}{\|y\|^4}\|y\|^2\\
&=\frac{\langle x,y\rangle^2}{\|y\|^2} -\frac{\langle x,y\rangle^2}{\|y\|^2}\\
&=0\end{align}

Now you can verify Pythagorean law for $x-p$ and $p$.